# Spring Security force logout when password change

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have 2 user role `ADMIN` and `USER`. `ADMIN` can change `USER`'s password. I want to force logout when user's password changed by `ADMIN`. I can save changed password and use them when next login. But I want to force logout to them.

```
UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(vendor.getUsername());
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to configure the session configuration under your security configuration as follows

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // this enables ConcurrentSessionFilter to allow us to read all sessions by using getAllPrincipals
    http
            .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(10)
            .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
            .expiredUrl("/login?expire");
    // Rest of the configuration
}
```

This enables you to call sessionRegistry.getAllSessions to manage the list of active session and expire them. SessionRegistry is autowired FYI.

```
List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();

for (Object principal: principals) {
    // Check for the principal you want to expire here
    List<SessionInformation> sessionInformations = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal);
    for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionInformations) {
        sessionInformation.expireNow();;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. It will search user's session in all session. Am i right?